# I am trying to upload video in laravel but not able to do so

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

Here is the Ajax part to add the video Url in the database.I am getting the value of Video title and video desc in database but not getting the url.

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="addVideo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
              aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-headerr">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" data-toggle="modal">Add New Video</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
                    <form class="image-upload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      @csrf
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type="tetx" name="addvideoTitle" id="AddvideoTitle" placeholder="Add a title"
                          class="form-control" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Discription</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Addvideodesc" id="Addvideodesc" placeholder="Add a discription"
                          class="form-control" />
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Add a video</label>
                        <input type="File" name="add-video" id="add-video" placeholder="Add a video to upload"
                          class="form-control" />
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="saveNewVideo">Save</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


   

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).on('click','#saveNewVideo',function(){
            
            var add_videotitle= $('#AddvideoTitle').val();
           var add_videoDesc= $('#Addvideodesc').val();
           var add_video= $('#add-video').val();
           $.ajax({
                                  type: "POST",
                                  dataType: "json",
        
        
        
                                  url: '{{ url('/event/saveEvent') }}',
                                  data: { 
                                    'add_videoDesc': add_videoDesc,
                                     'add_videotitle': add_videotitle,
                                     'add_video':add_video,
                                     _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                                  },
                                  success: function (data){
                                  }
        
        
                               });
                            });
                          });
        </script>
```

Controller code is written for adding video url in database I have written the value and getting the response but not actually saving the data in database.

```
 public function saveEvent(request $request){

        try{
        
        if(!$request->ajax())
            throw new \Exception('Not a valid Request');

        $event =new Event();
        $event->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $event->event_name=$request->event_name;
        $event->date=$request->event_date;
        $event->time=$request->event_time;
        $event->location=$request->event_location;
        $event->cost=$request->event_cost;
        $event->join_url=$request->event_join;  
        $event->add_video_title=$request->add_videotitle;  
        $event->add_video_desc=$request->add_videoDesc;
       
        if($request->hasfile('add_video'))
        {   
        $image = $request->file('add_video');
            $extention= $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $filename = time() . '.'. $extention;
            $path = public_path('video');
            $image->move('assets/video', $filename);
            $imageurl=$path."/". $filename;
           $event->video = $filename;
           
        }
        $event->save();
        return response()->json(['status'=>true,'message'=>'Event Added Successfully','data'=>$event]);
        }//end here try
        catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        return response()->json(['status'=>false,'message'=>$e->getMessage()]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please describe more like HTML, jQuery, Controller Code, and what you are actually doing.

Comment: hi Hitesh ,i have added the modal from where i wanted to save the video in my database i have added the complete controller code and ajax as well i just wanted to let you know the while saving the other 2 field the title and description is saving but the video url is not saving in database

Comment: You have a simple typo.  Your file upload is named `add-video`, but your Controller code is looking for `add_video`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel Docs, in the case of Ajax calls - you could, for example, store the token in an HTML meta tag::

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // and then include in your ajax header like this:
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
  
    $('#saveNewVideo').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '{{ url('/event/saveEvent') }}',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: (response) => {
                if (response) {
                    this.reset();
                    alert('Video has been uploaded successfully');
                }
            },
            error: function(response){
                $('#file-input-error').text(response.responseJSON.message);
            }
       });
    });
      
</script>
```

That code is checking for the extension but not the MIME type. You should use the appropriate MIME type:

```
Video Type     Extension       MIME Type

Flash           .flv            video/x-flv
MPEG-4          .mp4            video/mp4
iPhone Index    .m3u8           application/x-mpegURL
iPhone Segment  .ts             video/MP2T
3GP Mobile      .3gp            video/3gpp
QuickTime       .mov            video/quicktime
A/V Interleave  .avi            video/x-msvideo
Windows Media   .wmv            video/x-ms-wmv

If you are not sure about the MIME type of the file you are testing you can try $file->getMimeType()
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'video' => 'mimetypes:video/x-ms-asf,video/x-flv,video/mp4,application/x-mpegURL,video/MP2T,video/3gpp,video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo,video/x-ms-wmv,video/avi|max:204800'
    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('add_video')) {
        $unique_id = strtolower(str_replace('.', '', uniqid('', true)) . time());

        $videoFile = $request->file('add_video');

        $extension       = $videoFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $unique_id . '.' . $extension;
        $filepath        = $videoFile->storeAs('video', $fileNameToStore);
        
        $event->video = $filepath;
    }
    $event->save();
}
```

Store Files in Storage Folder

```
$file->storeAs('files', $fileName);
// storage/app/files/file.pdf
```

Store Files in Public Folder

```
$file->move(public_path('files'), $fileName);
// public/files/file.pdf
```

To display data on the front-end side.

```
$videoPath = !empty($pp_question->video) && Storage::exists($pp_question->video) ? Storage::url($pp_question->video) : asset(Storage::url('default/video.mp4');
```

Comment: Thanks Hitesh for the tremendous support.But being a beginner after applying the code its still not working for me.

Comment: Which problem are you facing?